# Where does .net core/.net 5 store JWT authentication token on server-side?

Tags: .net, .net-core, jwt, .net-5

I am configuring JWT Bearer token in my startup class and then generating JWT token when I receive valid login request. We send generated token to client and client is going to send it to server with every request in stateless implementation.

**[Authorize]** attribute authenticates each request from client on server end. I want to understand where does this token get stored on server-side for validation purpose as we are not storing it manually in the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not stored on the server side, it's decoded and validated on the server side. You have to send it with every request you want to be authenticated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not stored on the server side.
It is stored on the client side, sent to the server. Some signature checks are made (based on your jwt secret) and then it decodes the token to extarct data. The Authorize decorator is used by a Microsoft middleware that runs before entering your controller. You enable it in your Startup.cs when you configure your JWT parameters, etc...

You can check your data and your signature with that website : https://jwt.io/